# How to catch find button event & apply condition after record search?

Tags: sapb1

I have used a following code for navigation of records in sales order.

```
if (pVal.MenuUID == "1291") //Last Data Record

{

Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox("Last");

SAPbouiCOM.Conditions conditions = new SAPbouiCOM.Conditions();

SAPbouiCOM.Condition condition = null;

condition = conditions.Add();

condition.Alias = "U_pdocentry";

condition.Operation = SAPbouiCOM.BoConditionOperation.co_EQUAL;

int offset = oForm.DataSources.DBDataSources.Item(0).Offset;

string DocEntry = oForm.DataSources.DBDataSources.Item(0).GetValue("DocEntry", offset); Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox(DocEntry);

condition.CondVal = DocEntry; // Querying the DB Data source

oDBDataSource.Query(conditions);

oMatrix.LoadFromDataSource();

Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox("last record");

}
```

I want to apply this same condition when we search records by clicking on find button. I know the id for this menu is 1281 but when we click on button & then search records by cardcode or cardname and after that record get open. So, How can I apply the above(In code)conditon after record search?